# How running jython on nginx?

Tags: django, jython

How running [django-jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/) on FastCGI in [Nginx](http://nginx.org/)?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: You can't.

Although nginx can be used as a lightweight web server, its main strength is that it is a very good [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) and it is used primarily in this role.

You'll need to run your application in a servlet container (like tomcat), and then have nginx proxy to it.

See the [running django on jython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/jython/#running-django-on-jython) section at the django documentation.

Comment: Slightly disagree: nginx is a perfectly capable lightweight webserver, which is often used as a proxy. You're right though that proxying to tomcat is the right approach in this scenario.

Comment: Good point @DanielRoseman, I updated the answer to provide some context.